# How to alias namespaces in classes

Tags: c#, namespaces, .net-2.0

I have a class in my project, for example,

```
namespace BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder
{
    public class MyBigProjectsClass
    {
        public static string returnStringMethod()
        {
           return "Your a Star"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Now in another class I want to use this method let say,

```
namespace BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject
{
    public class MyBigProjectsClassABC
    {
        private void ABC()
        {
            string tooLong = BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder.MyBigProjectsClass.returnStringMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it short, I tried putting this,

```
using BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder;
```

> But NO gain, ONLy Pain !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax:

```
using MyAlias = BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder;
```

---

Though, the following will also work:

```
using BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder;

namespace BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject
{
    public class MyBigProjectsClassABC
    {
        private void ABC()
        {
            string tooLong = MyBigProjectsClass.returnStringMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using colAlias = BrightCompany.BigProjects.MyBigProject.ApplicationCodeFolder;

string tooLong = colAlias::MyBigProjectsClass.returnStringMethod();
```